# How to create a popup window when browser is set in fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension which helps developer to test multiple screens (Iphone, Android & Ipad..etc). I am using `chrome.windows.create` api to set the correct viewport based on the chosen one. I am facing a weird bug in `chrome.windows.create` api.

```
 chrome.windows.create({
        url: url,
        type: "popup",
        width: width,
        height: height,
        left: left,
        top: top,
        focused: true
 });
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create

If a user has set the browser in fullscreen, creating a new window also opens in fullscreen mode. It doesn't respect the given `width, height, left and top` options.

How to create a popup window in given size if the user has opened the browser in full screen mode?

Comment: Hey @kannanrbk, were you able to fix this ?

Comment: @prateek31 there is a crude bypass you can take by putting a `chrome.windows.update()` in the callback of your create function.

Answer (score 0):

the window object will refer to your browser, and screen object refers to your actual screen, so you can check if the browser is full screen by

```
if (window.innerHeight === screen.height &&
    window.innerWidth === screen.width)
```